# Concurrency with fs.writeFileSync using NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, concurrency

I have the following code written with NodeJS and ExpressJS:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
let port = 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/answers"));

const answersPath = __dirname + "/answers/answers.json";

app.patch("/new/answer", jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  try {
    const questionId = req.body.questionId;
    const answer = req.body.answer;

    const answersJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`${answersPath}`, "utf8"));

    if (answersJson[questionId]) {
      answersJson[questionId] = [...answersJson[questionId], answer];
    } else {
      answersJson[questionId] = [answer];
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(`${answersPath}`, JSON.stringify(answersJson));
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});

app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
```

What it basically does, it has an endpoint (`/new/question`), on which it receives as a JSON format, a `question` and an `answer`.
If the question exists already in the `answers.json` file, it adds the new answer to the list of answers for that question. If not, it creates a new question with a list of the answer.

Now, I've read the following article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-concurrency-in-node-js/

And what I understood from here, is that even though the endpoint would get called at the same time by two clients, both of the responses will be saved, one after the other - one of them will wait for the other one, i.e. the file will not get overwritten.

So my question is, is this true? NodeJS deals with concurrency on its own, or do I need to implement something to prevent this from happening?

Thank you, and sorry if this is a dumb question .

Answer (score 0):

Although `readFileSync()` and `writeFileSync()` might do what you want to achieve, you should avoid using synchronous functions in Node.js.

Synchronous functions will block the entire Node.js process, not just the a single Express route. This means your server will become unresponsive while reading or writing the file. This will become an issue if the file gets bigger.

Instead of using a file, you could keep the data only in memory. If you need to persist the data between server restarts, you can read it when the server starts and write it when the server stops. In this case it might be okay to use synchronous functions.